# Creating a custom tree view in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Is it possible to create a control like [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/32/screendn.jpg/)? I've tried so much, but I can't create a control exactly like this.

Comment: Sure it's possible.  What have you tried and where are you falling short?

Comment: with WPF it would be easy but with winforms less easier

Comment: You can start by looking this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23746/TreeView-with-Columns
and this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14741/Advanced-TreeView-for-NET

Comment: So far i've created a tree like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/845/sofara.jpg/ using draw text in OwnerDrawnTextMode and also a custom control for the tree like  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/newaqg.jpg/    I've lagging in the node bounds, i cant able to change the node bounds.

Comment: thanq AleWin i've already seen that controls, but no use. i would like to change the bounds of the node

Answer (score 1):

It is super easy to do in WPF once you have a fair grounding in the technology. You need to understand the following key concepts :

Control creation overview : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx I recommend you use a UserControl for this simple task.

DataContext : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: thanq sir but we have already started our project in winforms. we where in the middle of the project... Is there any way that i can host these custom WPF components in Winform?? Even if such hosting is possible does it supports drag and drop between winforms and WPF.... I need ur kind advice....

Comment: It is possible to host WPF components in winforms : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx And drag and drop works as well.

Comment: So far i've created a tree like this imageshack.us/photo/my-images/845/sofara.jpg using draw text in OwnerDrawnTextMode and also a custom control for the tree like imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/newaqg.jpg I've lagging in the node bounds, i cant able to change the node bounds.